# SQL Joining query using Selection

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table of tbl_order where columns are :

- id_order
- username
- delivery_date etc...

and other table tbl_order_foods where columns are :

- id_order
- id_food
- food_quantity etc

Here the sample pic of tbl_order table

[image]

and tbl_order_foods table

[image]

Here i am want to select all the foods with quantity with price and unit based on delivery_date.
Ex: Suppose On 2020-04-18 there are 3 orders where foods: tomato's are ordered total 15 kg (3 orders * 5 quantity * food_min_unit_amount * unit) and so on others foods.

how i can get the foodlist of total ordered quantity based on delivery_date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out GROUP BY with the SUM function, a good article from Tutorialspoint.com is [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-sum-function.htm). The only difference is that you are performing a JOIN to create the resulting table.

```
  SELECT DISTINCT [f.id_food], [o.delivery_date], SUM(f.food_quantity) as [delivered_sum_qty], SUM(f.food_total_price) as [sum_food_total_price]
  FROM tbl_order o LEFT JOIN tbl_order_foods f
  ON [o.id_order] = [f.id_order]
  GROUP BY [o.delivery_date];
```

If you need it, a pretty clear explanation of how to use JOIN is [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-using-joins.htm) as well.

Comment: If you add an attribute to the projection which is not in the grouping (in your case the id_food) MySQL will return the first value in the selection, which does not make too much sense.

Answer (score 1):

The method you need is the GROUP BY keyword.

SQL grouping works on the given attributes. According to your question this would be the `delivery_date`. In the projection (the attributes following the SELECT keyword) you then can use attributes you state after the GROUP BY keyword and aggregation functions e.g. SUM and MAX.

Based on your question you could get the total price for all orders on the given date like this:

```
SELECT order.delivery_date, SUM(food.food_quantity) as amount, SUM(food.food_total_price) as revenue
FROM tbl_order as order 
INNER JOIN tbl_order_foods as food ON order.id_order = food.id_order
GROUP BY order.delivery_date
```

This would result in a list like this:

```
date | amount | revenue
------------------------
05.01|     10 |  800.00
```

I don't know whether this is what you wish. If you also want to split it into order positions then you would GROUP BY the `food_name` as well and add it to the projection which then results in the SUM grouped by the orders on a given day of a given product.

```
SELECT order.delivery_date, food.food_name, SUM(food.food_quantity) as amount, SUM(food.food_total_price) as revenue
FROM tbl_order as order 
INNER JOIN tbl_order_foods as food ON order.id_order = food.id_order
GROUP BY order.delivery_date, food.food_name
```

Which would result in something like this.

```
date | food_name | amount | revenue
-----------------------------------
05.01|  Tomato   |   10   |  800.00
05.01|  Apple    |   5    |  400.00
```